# How do I resolve circular reference when creating a custom validation attribute that accesses entities in the same context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, circular-reference

I have an entity which contains a property that must be a valid transaction type.  The transaction types are defined in another entity.  I want to create a custom validation attribute to validate the transaction type by verifying it is in the transaction type table.

All the entities are defined in the same project (reverse engineered to code first EF).  The Db Context is in another project.  I access the entities using repository services.  The custom validation attribute is defined in its own project.

The Db Context references the entity project for the model builder and the DbSets.  The repository service references the entities as well.  The validation references the repository.  When I try to reference the validation project in the entities (where I will use the attribute), I get a circular reference error.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: When I separate entities from data access, I always keep an interface representation of repository inside my entities project. It might solve your problem if you can IoC your attribute with complete repository implementation.

Comment: I use an interface for the repository and it's in a separate project from the repository and the entities.  This is in a Prism project, so I'm using Unity for the dependency injection.  That doesn't resolve the problem.  Am I misunderstanding what you've said?

Comment: If your repository interfaces and entities are not in same project then  my suggestion won't work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the entity that was being used to validate the entries out of the project that had all the entities in it, and put it into its own project.  This allowed me to get around the circular reference.